# Convert Int Array to Ascii String

Tags: c

I have a Int Array like:

int testarray[20];

```
testarray[0] = 0x5A;
...
testarray[19] = 0x57;
```

and want to convert it to a Ascii String (char*). How can I do that?

Comment: Exactly what output do you want? Have you done any research so far? Tried anything?

Comment: copy into a char array?

Comment: whatever you do, do not forget the `'\0'` string terminator

Comment: @vt1111 You shouldn't accept answers so quickly. Give us a chance to peer review them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy `int` values into a `char` array and don't forget about string terminator.

Something like this:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 3

char *to_str(const int testarray[ARR_SIZE])
{
    char *str = malloc(ARR_SIZE + 1);
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; ++i)
        str[i] = testarray[i];
    str[ARR_SIZE] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

Comment: You're leaking all that memory. This is a great example of what _not_ to do.

Comment: Also not handling possible `NULL` at the callsite. And what's the point in hiving this off to a function and using dynamic allocation if you only support `ARR_SIZE` elements?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one. Always.

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings, okay, I deleted the driver code, that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: You're still leaking. At the very least you need to document (and/or tell the OP) that this memory must be freed. You didn't really address my points.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. I believe that OP can work with memory (if he writes in C!). You can write your own answer.

Comment: The OP doesn't even know how to turn `int`s into `char`s. Your answer is dangerous in its present form. Whether I write another answer or not. Cheers.